# Connecting Clients machine to MySQL Server machine

Tags: mysql, connection, remote-access

I've two machine.

Machine 1 (Server) : MySQL Server installed on it.

Machine 2 (Client) : MySQL Server **not** installed on it.

---

I would like connect from Machine 2 (Client) to MySQL Server on Machine 1 (Server).

I did following command on Machine 1 (Server) to grant permission to all clients :

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
```

Well, I need to connect MySQL Server from Client.

I've write below command in `cmd` on Machine 2 (Client) :

```
mysql -h 192.168.0.1 -u root -p
```

192.168.0.1 on above line is Machine 1 (Server) IP.

But following error has occur :

```
`mysql` is not recognaized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I guess need to install something like mysql connector or something else on Machine 2 (Client), isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other tool with good looking GUI. For example: [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/).

---

Then, you need to enable remote access. If you use windows, there is nice wizard for you to enable remote access with a few clicks. The wizard is located it at `MySQL Server 5.5\bin\MySQLInstanceConfig.exe`. Then
`Reconfigure Instance -> Next -> Standard Configuration -> Next -> Next`. You will see this screen.

[image]

Tick on "Enable root access from remote machines". Or you can manually configure it to allow remote access from `my.ini` file. See this link for [how to do it](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).

---

If having done above still does not allow you to connect to your MySQL. Please make sure that Firewall does not block MySQL port.

Comment: I've used [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/) but i get error `Error No 2003. Can't connect to MySQL server on 192.168.0.1 (10060)`. I take shot of [SQLyog configure](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/137086348636235_Untitled1.png) and [its error](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/137086349243568_Untitled2.png).

Comment: Updated my answer for enabling MySQL for remote machine

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea to do it,

1st: You have to give permission from machine 1 for machine 2. You should edit `httpd.conf` file

Listen `machine 2 ip` (192.168.0.*)

2nd: You have to give permission for phpmyadmin by following code-

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Database.* to 'username'@'ip or url' IDENTIFIED by 'password';`

You can check @ http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-connection-from-other-machine/

Comment: @sam- Where is `httpd.conf` dir ?

Comment: if you use WAMP server then you have to click to the wamp icon> Apache > httpd.conf

Comment: Which server you using in machine 1, give the full information here, otherwise it is really tough to figure out the solve

Comment: Look, I've just installed MySQL Server on machine 1, no more.