# MySQL Server - Installation & Configuration Slilenly

Tags: mysql, configuration, batch-file, installation

I need to install and configure MySQL Server silently.

For this, I have created a batch file :

```
echo Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...

msiexec /i "mysql-5.5.32-winx64.msi" /qn

echo Configurating MySQL Server...

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=DEVELOPER DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 Charset=utf8

echo Installation was successfully
```

I need to install MySQL Server and allow other Clients to connect Server by Checked `Enable root access from remote machines`.

By default that option is disable.

You can see GUI configuration here :

[image]

So, How set `Checked` that option into batch file ?

Comment: Why would you want to allow root access from remote machines?  That is a really poor choice from a security standpoint.  If you want root access from remote servers, force them to shell into the box and then login as root.

Comment: Might be more a "hack" than a true solution but can't you simply execute the GRANT ACCESS from remote machines to root using mysql / console ?

Comment: @MikeBrant: I know it's insecure choice. There are four local machines and i would like to share MySQL Server among them.

Comment: @RelevantUsername: I tried `GRANT ACCESS` but get me an error! For more information look at [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018772/connecting-clients-machine-to-mysql-server-machine)

Comment: @HamedKamrava Just because you want to have access for multiple remote machines, does not mean those remote machines need ROOT access.  Create a user for those machines. So can end up saving yourself some pain in the long run.  Say you have all machines accessing via root user and for some reason you have all connections being tied up (maybe a long running query is locking a table and stacking connections).  You now have no way to log onto the machine itself as root and kill the problem query, you would have to restart MySQL itself.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Fine, i just need to do all your suggestions silently in a batch file. My goal is when run that batch file do these works silently : [1] Install MySQL Server [2] Configure MySQL Server [3] Create a user as you said [4] Grant access to that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for answer to question of this topic , I should say for CHECK `Enable root access from remote machines` option you just need to add `SkipNetworking=no` to batch file configuration lines.

Above command allow to all clients connect to root user and it's not a wisely way.

As @MikeBrant said on comments it's worst way to sharing MySQL databases.

Instead that insecure way, we need to create a user and make `GRANT ACCESS` to that, like so :

```
@echo off
echo Installing MySQL Server. Please wait...

msiexec /i "mysql-5.5.32-win32.msi" /qn

echo Configurating MySQL Server...

"%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=mysql ServerType=DEVELOPER DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 Charset=utf8

echo MySQL has been installed successfully

setx PATH "%%Program Files%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin%;"

cd /
c:

mysql --user=root --password=mysql -e "CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';"
;

mysql --user=root --password=mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.* TO 'myuser'@'192.168.0.%' IDENTIFIED BY '123abc' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

Good Luck

Comment: this is giving error on win7 64bit, i am assuming its the programFiles path?

Comment: Yes it is. Change the programFiles path